# Необходимо сравнить элементы массива с ключами объекта

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть функция, которая принимает первым параметром объект, вторым - массив из цепочки свойств, по которому нужно пройти, чтобы получить значение.

Если какое-то из свойств не найдено или массив пустой - функция возвращает undefined.

Пример:

```
const obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: 'Привет!'
      }
    }
  }
}

optionalChaining(obj, ["a", "b", "c", "d"]) // Привет

optionalChaining(obj, ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]) // undefined
```

Comment: А где ваша реализация?

Comment: Ух кто-то по минусам прошелся.. без аргументов

Comment: Вопрос закрыт - ответ не получен. Поэтому во: `function chain(obj, arr) { let prop = arr.shift(), innerValue = obj[prop]; if( arr.length == 0 ) return obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? innerValue : undefined; return innerValue instanceof Object ? chain(innerValue, arr) : undefined; }`  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Кажется, проверка на `.hasOwnProperty()` — избыточное ограничение. Эта функция вернёт `undefined` при вызове, скажем, `chain([], ["map", "constructor"])`, хотя `[].map.constructor` не `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function optionalChaining(obj, path){
    let cur = obj;
    
    for(prop of path){
        if(cur[prop])
            cur = cur[prop];
        else
            return undefined;
    }
    
    return cur;
}

const obj = {a: {b: {c: {d: 'Привет!'}}}};

console.log(optionalChaining(obj, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']));
console.log(optionalChaining(obj, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']));
```

Comment: * `for( let prop ...` , `if( cur[prop] )` — не очень надежная проверка, потому что свойство может содержать пустую строку или ноль)

Comment: да, как-то забыл о таком варианте